# what is the significance of using ROUND function when calculating averages in SQL?

Tags: sql, function, average

The query goes like

`ROUND(AVG(CAST(trip_duration AS int64)/60,2)) as Duration`

1. why is the ROUND function used
2. are there any other significant function that needs to be added while performing averages.

here a big query public data set was used for the demonstration of merging & multiple sources module and the prime objective of this query is to calculate the number of trips from the newyork citybike trips data table.

Comment: AVG with 2 arguments? I've never seen that before. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Column trip_duration data type?

Comment: Why round? Well, because you want the number rounded. The number gets rounded to two decimal places. Probably because you are not interested in decimal places beyond that.

Comment: `ROUND` function is commonly used in `SQL` while dealing with `AVG` because, the `AVG` will return so many decimals and if we need to avoid that, we round it. **See this fiddle:** https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=fe006226ddf96484ac8dad9b246b2611

Comment: Column trip_duration is of int data type only. since big query stores numbers in a 64 bit memory system , which is why there's a 64 after integer in this case. @jarlh